# Passing dynamic props React-native

Tags: properties, react-native

I have simple navigation

```
 if (routeId === 'Page1') {
  return (
    <Page1
        navigator={navigator} />
  );
}
if (routeId === 'Page2') {
  return (
    <Page2 
      navigator={navigator} />

  );
}
```

Then on the list on page one I bind the function to each row, and the object to pass. (c)

```
   render(){
     this.state.listData.map((c, i) => {
        return <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.visitPage.bind(this, c)} key={ i } style={ styles.cContainer }>
        <Image source={{uri:c.avatar}} style={ styles.circular }>
        </Image>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{c.name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
   }
  }
```

Now how can I get this object to go to page 2??
In visitPage I have...

```
visitPage(){
  this.props.navigator.push({
    id:'Page2',
    name:'Page2',
    passProps:{data:this} //iOS only uses passProps??  
  });
}
```

Ive also tried

```
visitPage(){
  this.props.navigator.push({
    id:'Page2',
    name:'Page2',
    data:this
  });
}
```

Then on Page 2 in the constructor, I set the data to null, and on page mount, read the properties.

```
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
     console.log(this.props);// Returns my navigator object, but no properties along with it.
    this.state = {
       page2Data: this.props.data,
    };
  }

  onComponentWillMount(){
     console.log(this.props.data); // Returns undefined 
     this.setState({page2Data: this.props.data});
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use passProps, you need to attach the property to your component like this:

```
if (routeId === 'Page1') {
  return (
    <Page1 {...route.passProps} navigator={navigator} />
  );
}
if (routeId === 'Page2') {
  return (
    <Page2 {...route.passProps} navigator={navigator}  />

  );
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
this.props.navigator.push({
    id: 1,
    passProps: {
        name: 'Chris',
        location: 'some location'
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks!!!  so simple.  Im finding the lack of documentation to be quite hard with react-native.  Maybe I just suck at reading it..lol

Comment: @ChrisGeirman I just submitted a pr, hope they are ok with it! Also decided to post a medium article about it, check it out https://medium.com/@dabit3/react-native-navigator-navigating-like-a-pro-in-react-native-3cb1b6dc1e30#.5h1idjx2f

Comment: Quality article, Nader! Very worthwhile read. Thanks... I'll share a link in the next newsletter and will look for the PR as well.